# Shared file format for DAW

Tags: daw, audacity, garageband

Newbie question: I record 2 tracks (voice, rhythm guitar) and I want to get these to my buddy who will lay a lead guitar track on top. I am using Audacity. He is using Garage Band. What file format should I use to send to him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no standard DAW file format. The best you can do is exporting/importing WAV files.

You may try Reaper, it works on Mac and PC and is not too expensive.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Thanks for confirming that there is not standard DAW file format. Do you recommend WAV over other uncompressed formats like OGG?

Comment: OGG is a compressed lossy file format. It has been developed as an alternative of MP3 when there was some patent restrictions. I would advice you to keep record in WAV (uncompress) file when the project is not finished. And when all is done (mixing, reverb, etc), render your project in a compressed format if you want to share it in a compact file. There exists lossless compression (FLAC…) but are less efficient than lossy compression and have some compatibility issue since not all software support them.

Comment: Note that if you're sending two independent files with no specified method to sync them that you need to ensure both files start at the same point in time in your DAW, even if that means the first minute may be silence. This allows the receiver to just butt them up to the start of their timeline & guarantee sync.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Thanks, good point